# is it safe to send many get requests from front-end (react) to back-end (spring-boot) to stimulate real-time application?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, frontend, backend

We have a front-end developed using react library and a back-end developed using spring framework, the application goal is to keep track of a company bank operations.

Instead of using an MVC design pattern in front-end, we decided to get rid of the model layer, to save time, as an example, when the front-end sends a save wire transfer request to the back end, in spring we verify if the user has enough balance ..., and if everything is okay, we update his balance in the database, here is now the most important part, instead of creating a model layer in the front end to update the balance if the transaction went successfully, we send a get request and update the whole data again after each save,update and delete , and to stimulate real-time application, we send get requests every second (Table content data that holds previously made transactions and current balance ...)

Is this a safe approach? the estimated users are at maximum 100, and the back end is hosted in a 4 processors server

Comment: may be sockets can help you here

Comment: @Aman Sadhwani we have arleady made a search about it, unfortunatly there is not enough ressources about it in spring community (all exemples i found are about chat application), and since it doesn't use http protocol to send and receive data, we excluded that option

Comment: I would say it is safe. As I see it, the worst case scenario is that some request would take time so, as long as you don't expect the GET request to complete in order, it shouldn't be a problem. 
If you are afraid of the resource consumption, you could look at making the back-end reactive (webflux) and/or the spring-native project (https://docs.spring.io/spring-native/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/)

By the way, number of users is not so important as the number of request/sec (or min)

Comment: @grekier thank you for you comment, we will test it then, and eventually we will give a feedback about it